# Maintaining synchronized db across different thread and servers

Tags: java, synchronization, singleton

I think I'm getting a little burned out, so I apologize if this is a silly question. Suppose I have the following code:

```
    public void updatePrices()
    {
        synchronized (singleton_price_db)
        {

            singleton_price_db.modifyPrices();

            singleton_propagator.propagatePricesToOtherServers();
        }
    }
```

Now, when the executing thread runs through this code, it will lock the price db (singleton_price_db), then alert the singleton file propagator to propagate the updated prices to the other servers. However, as the singleton propagator is running, I won't have the sync lock anymore, will I? How can this be handled? (I need to synchronize both the modifying prices on RAM and as it's being propagated to the other servers. I can't make the propagatePricesToOtherServers() method be allowed to be called by the executing thread either, since this will cause a host of other sync issues.)

Edit: I can elaborate what I'm trying to do a little further, but a solution may not exist using my design. Essentially, I have two threads which need to have a sync block around a data structure. When the first thread finishes with its task, it needs to pass the sync block to the propagator thread (the second one), without a chance of modification from any other thread. Without adding a good deal of extra machinery, like an overlying manager thread, I don't see an immediate solution, so that may be how this problem can be handled.